# Python screen record using ImageGrab

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, screen-capture

I got the code to record screen in python using pillow ImageGrab which isn't working properly in my python 3.5 version. The frames of video keep on decreasing in size.[image: like this]

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import time


last_time = time.time()
while(True):
    # 800x600 windowed mode
    printscreen =  np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,800,600)))
    print('loop took {} seconds'.format(time.time()-last_time))
    last_time = time.time()
    cv2.imshow('window',cv2.cvtColor(printscreen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. As you are using `cv2.imshow()` it shows a window on the screen and this is again captured in the `ImageGrab`. So if you don't show the image but only save them as a video, you won't see this problem.

To see that it's working as intended you can do this,

```
printscreen =  np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,200,200)))
```

which will capture only the top left 200 X 200 pixels of your screen. Now drag the `opencv` output window away from the top left corner of your screen you will see no such effect of having a window inside a window.

Comment: its working fine with others who have used in their application. I don't want to save the video .

Comment: maybe they didn't show it on the screen. It simply captures the current screen as an image. Now if you have an image of your screen inside a window of your screen you will get this kind of output.

Comment: The same code was used by others in which they are getting the exact screen record video and not saving them and also they are displaying it.

Comment: Thanks @Ultraviolet I just moved cv2 window at the side and its working fine now